# How to convert given number of days to years, months and days in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, datediff

I am trying to get the date and time duration between the Loan taken and Paid date. I used the PHP date and time functions, but it is not always accurate. How can I do this accurately in MySQL?

Let assume two dates, The Loan taken date

> 2009-05-24

and the Loan return date

> 2012-04-30

I write a MySQL query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2012-04-30', '2009-05-24') `total_days`;
```

return 1072 days, which is roughly 2 Years, 11 Months, 12 Days.

> Please do not answer with PHP code, I already try it. Here is the
>   code.

The function below uses PHP >= 5.3 functions and convert days to years, months and days.

```
function date_interval($date1, $date2)
{
    $date1 = new DateTime($date1);
    $date2 = new DateTime($date2);

    $interval = date_diff($date2, $date1);
    return ((($y = $interval->format('%y')) > 0) ? $y . ' Year' . ($y > 1 ? 's' : '') . ', ' : '') . ((($m = $interval->format('%m')) > 0) ? $m . ' Month' . ($m > 1 ? 's' : '') . ', ' : '') . ((($d = $interval->format('%d')) > 0) ? $d . ' Day' . ($d > 1 ? 's' : '') : '');
}
```

The function below uses PHP >= 5.2 functions and convert days to years, months and days.

```
function date_interval($date1, $date2)
{
    $diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

    $years = floor($diff / (365 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (30 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60 * 24));

    return (($years > 0) ? $years . ' Year' . ($years > 1 ? 's' : '') . ', ' : '') . (($months > 0) ? $months . ' Month' . ($months > 1 ? 's' : '') . ', ' : '') . (($days > 0) ? $days . ' Day' . ($days > 1 ? 's' : '') : '');
}
```

Comment: How many days are there in a month? 28? 29? 30? 31?

Comment: You'll probably need a stored procedure or function to do that in MySQL.

Comment: not good for months and years (second months is 28 days only)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is as follows:

1. In order to find the difference between days you need to use [`datediff()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)
2. `datediff()` returns the difference in days.
3. In order to convert days to a date, so you can get the number of years etc you need to use  [`from_days()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-days)
4. `from_days()` doesn't really work before 1582, to quote from the documentation:

   > "Use FROM_DAYS() with caution on old dates. It is not intended for use
   >   with values that precede the advent of the Gregorian calendar (1582)"

   The minimum is 1582 as this was when Europe converted from the Julian to the Gregorian calender.
5. 0000-00-00 + 6 days is 0000-01-06, which is earlier than 1582.

This effectively means that MySQL date-functions are useless to you.

You ask for this to be done in MySQL *"accurately"*. As you can't use date functions you're going to have to make up your own. This *will not* be accurate. How many days are there in a year? It's certainly not always 365. How many days are there in a month?

I would highly recommend doing this in PHP.

However, as you're adamant that you don't want to do so, you're going to have to cheat.

Add the date 1600-01-01 to *everything*. Then remove 1600 years, 1 month and 1 day from your answer at the end. I only use this date because it's greater than 1582 and it's a nice round number. Anything would work really but the earlier the better so you don't run into problems.

Assuming we've built the following table:

```
create table dates (a date, b date);
insert into dates
values ( str_to_date('2012-04-30','%Y-%m-%d')
       , str_to_date('2012-04-24','%Y-%m-%d')
        );

insert into dates
values ( str_to_date('2012-04-30','%Y-%m-%d')
       , str_to_date('2009-05-24','%Y-%m-%d')
        );
```

The following query will get what you want:

```
select extract(year from from_days(days)) - 1600
     , extract(month from from_days(days)) - 1
     , extract(day from from_days(days)) - 1
  from ( select to_days(a) - to_days(b) + 
                to_days(str_to_date('1600-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')) as days
           from dates ) as b
```

[Here's a SQL Fiddle to prove it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d1a6/12).

Once again, this is really quite hacky and not really recommended.

Comment: It is quite weird mysql has nothing easy set up for this issue. I hope they will extend functionality soon :)

Comment: Used the PHP version. In 2014.

Answer (score 6):

Use MySQL's [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR
       , '2009-05-24'
       , '2012-04-30'
       ) AS Years,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH
       , '2009-05-24'
           + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2009-05-24', '2012-04-30') YEAR
       , '2012-04-30'
       ) AS Months,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY
       , '2009-05-24'
           + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2009-05-24', '2012-04-30') YEAR
           + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2009-05-24', '2012-04-30') MONTH
       , '2012-04-30'
       ) AS Days
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/783).

Comment: Short, concise and right. The correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I used this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR
       , '2010-08-29'
       , '2014-09-18'
       ) AS Years,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH
       , '2010-08-29'
           + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2010-08-29', '2014-09-18') YEAR
       , '2014-09-18'
       ) AS Months,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY
       , '2010-08-29'
           + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2010-08-29', '2014-09-18') MONTH
       , '2014-09-18'
       ) AS Days
```

Comment: Using the timestampdiff funtion from cjmancor works for me > TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2010-08-29', '2014-09-18')

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF('2012-04-30', '2009-05-24')), '%Y-%m-%d') AS `total_days`
```

Comment: The function does not seem to be working if the difference is less than a year o.O I was not aware of that.