# Mysql query to convert total days to years, months and days

Tags: mysql, date

I need to convert a total days to a years, months and days format using a mysql query.

My current code its this one:

```
SELECT  nombre, fecha_de_inicio, DATEDIFF(NOW(), fecha_de_inicio) as days_employed
FROM    cms_trabajadores 
GROUP   BY days_employed desc
```

Right now the result its like this (3 columns):

Name Started date and days_employed

Aaron, 2007-06-25 00:00:00, 2759

Where 1st column its name, 2nd column started date and 3rd and last column total worked days.

I'm looking to have, total working days like:

7 years, 6 months and 21 days

Thanks in advance for your help.

I do have the started date on my table and I'm always comparing vs the current day.

Comment: You should really do this in a server-sided scripting language. What are you using?

Comment: You should check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765995/convert-days-to-years-months-days-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

### # UPDATE - 1:

After some corrections, the following query gave the exact result marked by you as expected:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
    nombre, 
    fecha_de_inicio, 
    FLOOR(PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(fecha_de_inicio, '%Y%m')) / 12) as years_employed, 
    PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD((CASE WHEN DAY(NOW()) >= DAY(fecha_de_inicio) THEN NOW() ELSE DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) END), INTERVAL -(FLOOR(PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(fecha_de_inicio, '%Y%m')) / 12)) YEAR), '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(fecha_de_inicio, '%Y%m')) as months_employed,
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), fecha_de_inicio) - DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(CONVERT(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT((CASE WHEN DAY(NOW()) >= DAY(fecha_de_inicio) THEN NOW() ELSE DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) END), '%Y-%m-'), RIGHT('0' + DAY(fecha_de_inicio), 2)), DATE), INTERVAL -1 DAY), fecha_de_inicio) as days_employed
FROM    
    cms_trabajadores 
ORDER BY 
    years_employed desc, 
    months_employed desc, 
    days_employed desc
```

### Column calculation description:

- **years_employed** : `FLOOR(PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(fecha_de_inicio, '%Y%m')) / 12)` - difference in years between current date and employment date counted as difference in months divided by 12 and with remainder left out
- **months_employed** : `PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD((CASE WHEN DAY(NOW()) >= DAY(fecha_de_inicio) THEN NOW() ELSE DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) END), INTERVAL -(FLOOR(PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(fecha_de_inicio, '%Y%m')) / 12)) YEAR), '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(fecha_de_inicio, '%Y%m'))` - here, using `PERIOD_DIFF` function, difference in months is counted substracting first 1 month from `NOW()` **only if** `DAY(NOW()) < DAY(fecha_de_inicio)`, then substracting the difference in years and, after that, making a `DATEDIFF` between the product of substraction and `fecha_de_inicio`; this should get the months remainder
- **days_employed** : `DATEDIFF(NOW(), fecha_de_inicio) - DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(CONVERT(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT((CASE WHEN DAY(NOW()) >= DAY(fecha_de_inicio) THEN NOW() ELSE DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) END), '%Y-%m-'), RIGHT('0' + DAY(fecha_de_inicio), 2)), DATE), INTERVAL -1 DAY), fecha_de_inicio)` - this value is counted substracting first 1 month from `NOW()` **only if** `DAY(NOW()) < DAY(fecha_de_inicio)`, then the new date is built using `DATE_FORMAT` taking Year and Month from `NOW()` prepared in the first step (conditional -1 Month step) and with Day taken from `fecha_de_inicio` substracted then by 1 DAY. Having such  number of days which in fact is the difference in month between `NOW()` and `fecha_de_inicio` but converted to days, we substract this value from the `DATEDIFF(NOW(), fecha_de_inicio)` strict difference in days between the two dates. This gives us a days remainder

I hope it may occur helpful. In case of doubts, please write.

Comment: Hi T_G it gave me an error as days_employed its a dynamic field. MySQL Error: Unknown column 'days_employed' in 'group statement'

Comment: Hi. I've finally managed to correct the answer to get the result marked by you as expected. I hope it helps. Regards.