# Calculating the difference between two dates in years in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two dates in years using MySQL, but the **DATEDIFF** function seems to return the difference in days instead. For example, when I use the statement

```
SELECT DATEDIFF("2018-06-25", "2017-06-15") as years;
```

it returns "375" which is the difference in days rather than years.

I would like to know how I can get the difference between two dates in years using MySQL. Is there a specific function or method I should use to achieve this? I want the result to be the exact difference in years, considering any additional months or days.

Comment: See this article for how --> 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765995/how-to-convert-given-number-of-days-to-years-months-and-days-in-mysql
Now sure its about php , but ignore that, the MySQL command you want is in the answers.

Comment: NOTE - When you say AS YEARS in your example, you are just giving the variable a name, that is NOT a command to make it automatically convert into years.

Comment: I understand that 'years' is just a variable name. I have seen the question you provided earlier, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer because I am a beginner and I want to fully understand the solution. Specifically, I am having trouble comprehending the table or method used for converting the difference in days into years.

Comment: I will mine the thing you need one sec.

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF('2018-06-25', 2018-06-25')), '%Y-%m-%d') AS `total_days`

Something like that perhaps?

Comment: I tested that example and it has some sort of issue with it, but this is the concept here, just have to look into it a bit more.  Hopefully someone can fix that example but this is the idea here.

Comment: NOTE - I think that if it is less than a year, that it will fail because its not even a full value.  Reading the notes that seems to be part of the issue.  That being said the current answer seems like what you want.

Comment: Thank U soo much my issue is resolved now i was just need year not months or days i will use if condition if the difference is less then 1 year I will return zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is TIMESTAMPDIFF

`SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, "2017-06-15", "2018-06-25");`

That lets you specify YEAR, MONTH, MINUTE, etc.

EDIT: this returns time from first to the second date, so for a positive number, put the earlier date first.

Comment: This pretty much works as he wants, however, because those dates are NOT a full year, the  returned value is Negative 1 so you have to consider that.

Comment: it is a full year but...yeah, I reversed the parameters.  Put dates in temporal order to get a positive number

Comment: ohh ok that makes sense, yeah I see the date update., this should be the accepted answer i think.